# How can I make hyperlinks in Irssi/Terminal.app be underlined?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal.app, hyperlink, irssi

I'm using Irssi via Terminal.app on a Mac. I realise you can open links in the default browser using `CMD + Double-click` but I'd like some visual indication in Irssi that links are, well, links (such as by underlining them).

Is there some way I can either do this in Irssi itself or Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the way you can change the text color in the terminal with special character sequences, you can set bold, underline, and background colors on terminal text.

You can find a list of examples here - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt#List_of_colors_for_prompt_and_Bash

Though, depending on your runtime environment, you may have to prefix these sequences with \033 instead of \e.

```
// node.js
var yellowUnderline = '\033[4;33m';
var reset = '\033[0m';
console.log("url: " yellowUnderline + "http://superuser.com" + reset)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. However, what I'm looking for is a way to automatically add something like this. Your suggestion seems to be about manually adding the effect (unless I misunderstood). The links are being detected on some level because if you command-click, they open in a browser so I thought there might be a way.